# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Entity Framework 5 except local

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm getting error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." in all environment Dev,QA and Production but not on local development machine. If I point my local application to QA database it works fine but on QA application pointing to QA database getting this error.

On my local machine I've windows 7 and all other enviroment DEV,QA and Production using IIS 6.

I don't know which line i'm getting error because I don't get this error in debug mode on local machine. But here is the code and stack trace.

```
foreach (var videoTag in videoModel.VideoTags.ToList())
        {
            if (videoTag.TagName != null)
            {
                // if tag already exists continue to next tag
                if (video.VideoTags.Any(x => x.TagName == videoTag.TagName)) continue;

                var newVideoTag = _entityFactory.Create<VideoTag>();
                var userName = Util.GetCurrentUserName();
                newVideoTag.TaggedBy = userName;
                newVideoTag.TaggedOn = DateTime.Now;

                var tag = _tagRepository().Get(x => x.TagName == videoTag.TagName);
                if (tag == null)
                {
                    tag = _entityFactory.Create<Tag>();
                    tag.TagName = videoTag.TagName;
                }
                newVideoTag.Tag = (Tag)tag;
                newVideoTag.TagName = videoTag.TagName;
                newVideoTag.VideoId = video.VideoId;

                video.VideoTags.Add(newVideoTag);
            }
        }

        // remove tags if removed
        var videoTagToRemove = video.VideoTags.Where(videoTag => !videoModel.VideoTags.Any(x => x.TagName == videoTag.TagName)).ToList();
        foreach (var videoTag in videoTagToRemove.ToList())
        {
            _videoRepository().DeleteVideoTag(videoTag);
            //video.VideoTags.Remove(videoTag);
        }

        var optStatus = _videoRepository().Update(video);
        if (!optStatus.Status)
        {
            throw new Exception(optStatus.ExceptionMessage); // line no  309
        }
```

StackTrace:
at FordTube.Web.UI.Controllers.VideoController.UpdateVideo(VideoModel videoModel) in E:\TFS\Projects\Ford\FordTube\Dev\Source\Ford.FordTube\Web.UI\Controllers\VideoController.cs:line 309 at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)